# Finding parametric equations

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A new Tennis racket has shape given by the polar equation $r= \sqrt{\cos 2\theta}$.

[image]

a) Give parametric equation of the boundary curve of the racket and state the values of $t$ which take you exactly once around the boundary.
b) Give an integral that finds the circumference of the head of the racket (the length of the frame of the racket)
c) Give an integral that finds the area $A$ of the head of the racket (the shaded area above).
d) Give an integral that finds the average $x$ coordinate of the head of the racket (the sweet spot)

Comment: This is standard stuff, *Lemniscate of Bernoulli,* see for instance MathWorld.

Answer (score 1):

A few guidelines:

a) $x=r(t)\cos t$, $y=r(t)\sin t$

b) $L=\oint_C v(t)\; dt$, where $v(t)=\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}$

c) $A=\frac{1}{2}\oint xdy - y dx $